# C# putting 4 numbers in order from smaller to greater(easy)

Tags: math

So I have an assingment to order 4 numbers from smaller to larger and if two or more numbers are equal, they are only written once. Example:

1.)
Input: -5 4 -5 1
Output: -5 1 4

2.)
Input: -5 -5 -5 1
Output: -5 1

I am not allowed to use functions or loops or matrix fields.

This is what I have so far:

```
int a, b, c, d;

        Console.WriteLine("Vnesite prvo stevilo: ");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Vnesite drugo stevilo: ");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Vnesite tretje stevilo: ");
        c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Vnesite cetrto stevilo: ");
        d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //a
        if(a>b && a>c && a> d)
        {




        }
```

Comment: List all cases naively: `a,b,c,d`, `a,b,d,c`, `a,c,d,b`, ... Do an `if` statement for each case: `if (a < b && b < c && c < d) { ... }`. Then "factor out" `a < b` so you have `if (a < b) { ... } else { ... }` where the first block contains all cases where `a < b` and the second block contains the rest. Then do the same "factoring out" for the statements inside those blocks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by listing cases

Comment: All different possible permutations of `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. There are 24 cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to tell me

Comment: If you could write a case so I could understand

Comment: Start with a program that looks like `if (a<b && b<c && c<d) { ... } else if (a<b && b<d && d<c) { ... } else if (<next permutation>) { ... } ...`. Then (if you like) refine the statements so that you don't repeat `a<b` over and over again.